# GitLab CI with Visual Studio 2017 Devenv and power shell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, gitlab

I'm working on an automated build with GitLab CI.
The Runner is on Windows Server 2012, and configured to use "shell".

The project I need to build uses Microsoft Visual Studio development environment (The MSBuild doesn't support the installer project.)

I can build in PowerShell using the command lines:

```
$VS2017_Dev_Build = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"  
& $VS2017_Dev_Build UTFA.sln  /Project Setup_vs2017 /Rebuild Release
```

I translated this to the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
variables:
    VS2017_Dev_Build:  "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" 
stages:
  - build

#Purpose: Build solution
build:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  script:
  - echo building...
  - & $VS2017_Dev_Build UTFA.sln  /Project Setup_vs2017 /Rebuild Release
  except:
  - tags
```

GitLab is complaining about the `'&'` symbol in the 2nd line after `script:`.

What is the correct syntax for running the above PowerShell command lines, in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: Whats the error message you receive?

Answer (score 1):

If you try it in a YAML validator (separate from GitLab's CI linter), you should see that this is a YAML level issue. I'm no YAML expert, but ampersand is a special character and thus needs to be escaped. I believe single or double quotes would work in your case:

```
 - '& $VS2017_Dev_Build UTFA.sln  /Project Setup_vs2017 /Rebuild Release'
```